# PHP delete row on cvs file with if statement

Tags: php, sql, row

i have csv file have 50,000 data like

```
SadieMMadsen@armyspy.com,aiy2Aikei,TX,77002

DavidMWest@gustr.com,deiCohji6ee,TX,7705
```

i need to correct it by deleting row have 4 or less  digits zipcode

Comment: Read each row in turn, test the zipcode and write to a new file as required, then copy the new file to the old file

Comment: Thanks for reply 
but it's 50,000 data 
php code will be better

Comment: So what if it's 50,000 data rows? The process is no different for 5 rows or 500,000 rows.... and that is how to do it in PHP

Comment: If you want an alternative solution, create a temporary database table in MySQL, use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) to load the file to the temporary table, delete the rows with 4-digit zip codes in the temporary table, then use MySQL's [SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) to write the temporary table out to file again

Comment: @MarkBaker The guy cant cope with `read line/validate/write new master` and you want him to start using a database as an intermediary mechanism. Are you paying attention?

Comment: I got the impression that he was having problems with the volume of data, didn't stop to think that he might simply be wanting somebody to actually write all the code for him

Comment: Zip 001234 is a valid zip. Can you be sure that a four-digit zip code is not because leading zeroes never made it to the csv file?